# Convert latex of paper to slide

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I have written a paper in latex and I want to convert it directly to slide(like beamer ), for presentation. Is there any code to do it?

Comment: There won't be anything more direct than writing the paper using beamerarticle (see section 21.2, "Creating Handouts Using the Article Mode" of the [beamer documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). Even then, it may be more work than you have time for. I'd strongly recommend copying and pasting selected figures from the paper into slides, and then writing text around it. Good, readable slides aren't automatically created from good, readable paragraphs.

Comment: If your problem had been solved, please write down the solution, if not, describe you problem more detailed or write down what you did. Others may find this information useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, but not so nice version would be

```
\begin{document}
\newcount\anzahlSeiten
\anzahlSeiten=10 %if it throws an error, decrease the number and include the last one manually. Number must be even, because it includes always a pair
\newcount\ipp
\ipp=0

\loop
%\begin{frame} %with frames it doesn't loop somehow
\global\advance\ipp by1
\includegraphics[page=\ipp, width=0.49\textwidth]{test1}
\hfill
\global\advance\ipp by1
\includegraphics[page=\ipp, width=0.49\textwidth]{test1}
%\end{frame}
\newpage
\ifnum\ipp<\anzahlSeiten\repeat

\end{document}
```